# What Does "Required Background Modes" In Xamarin.iOS Actually Mean?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, core-bluetooth

I have been working with Xamarin.Forms based app that uses Audio, Location, Bluetooth LE, and other Background Processing both on Android and iOS. For iOS, I have to set the *Required Background Modes* in `Info.plist` file. Right now, I have `App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay`, `App registers for location updates`, and `App communicates using CoreBluetooth` enabled but the app kills itself after sometime while receiving data from a Bluetooth LE sensor.

Looking online, I found almost no explanation of all the following background modes, even on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/registering-applications-to-run-in-background#application-registration-categories)

Could someone please explain what does each background mode enable and when should we use which one. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: it means that you app can scan for devices while it is on background as well

Comment: be careful with the use on iOS though. Might easily get rejected. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html

Answer (score 0):

Open info.plist with `iOS Manifest Editor` , you could find the following option in Background Modes.

[image]

And i think the explanation is clear in official docs.

[image]

Comment: Reading the docs, I could not tell what the "Background processing" mode is for. Neither, I can tell if I also need "External accessory communication" mode for BLE communication (I don't need that though, from Apple docs). Since my app is crashing in the background. I was thinking of adding "Background processing" mode but I am simply not sure.

Comment: Only `Uses Bluetooth LE accessory` or `Acts as bluetooth accessory` is needed , check https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW7.

Comment: Do you also add permission `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` and `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription` in info.plist ?

Comment: Yes, in my case, I only need `Uses Bluetooth LE accessory` in terms of BLE mode. And yes, I also set `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` and  `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription` permissions.